# Triangular Node has Unexpected Inner Space

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, nodes, shapes

I was expecting a much tighter triangle around the text in this example, similar to the inner spacing around the text in the rectangle nodes. How would I tighten up the inner spacing?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [trusty/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3, 
    ultra thick,draw=black},
    corp/.style={rectangle,ultra thick,
inner sep=4pt,minimum size=1.3cm, rounded corners=4mm,draw=black}
]

\node (opco) at (0,0) [corp] {entity};
\node (holdco)  [corp][below=of opco] {another entity};
\node (trust)  [trusty][ right=of holdco] {trust entity};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output from above latex]

Answer (score 9):

According to the doc for `regular polygon` (`pgfmanual` v3.1.9a, sec. 71.3 "Geometric Shapes" or [this online version](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.regular:polygon)), border of this shape is always constructed using the *incircle*, hence may result in a larger visual `inner sep`.

`tikz` has a `isosceles triangle` shape, which when set with `isosceles triangle apex angle=60` (and maybe `shape border rotate=90` as well) will have an equilateral triangle border. But this time node text is not at the center of node.

You may use `regular polygon` with a small negative `inner sep` as a workaround.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
  equilateral triangle/.style={
    shape=isosceles triangle,
    isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
    shape border rotate=90,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, equilateral triangle, label=isosceles triangle] {text};
  \node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3, label=regular polygon]
    at (3,0) {text};
  \node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3, label={[align=center]regular polygon\\negative inner sep}, inner sep=-.1em]
    at (6,0) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]